# Why Firebase Realtime database not working?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a realtime database but it is not working.

```
private lateinit var databaseReference: DatabaseReference
```

After this, in oncreate, I am calling a function call buyer().

```
private fun buyer(){
    findViewById<EditText>(R.id.shopName).visibility = View.GONE
    findViewById<EditText>(R.id.shopStreet).visibility = View.GONE
    findViewById<EditText>(R.id.shopCity).visibility = View.GONE
    findViewById<EditText>(R.id.shopState).visibility = View.GONE
    findViewById<EditText>(R.id.pinCode).visibility = View.GONE
    findViewById<EditText>(R.id.shopGstIn).visibility = View.GONE
    val letsGoButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.letsGo)
    val layoutParams = letsGoButton.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    layoutParams.verticalBias = 0.5f
    letsGoButton.layoutParams = layoutParams
    letsGoButton.setOnClickListener {
        val sName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.name).text.toString()
        val sContactNo = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.contactNo).text.toString()
        val sUserName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.username).text.toString()
        val sType = "buyer"
        if (sName.isNotEmpty() && sContactNo.isNotEmpty() && sUserName.isNotEmpty() && sType.isNotEmpty()) {
            val userMap = hashMapOf(
                "name" to sName,
                "contactNo" to sContactNo,
                "username" to sUserName,
                "type" to sType
            )

            val userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
            val userMap2 = hashMapOf(
                "name" to sName,
                "userId" to userId
            )

            db.collection("user").document(userId).set(userMap).addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Buyer Account Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userId)
                databaseReference.setValue(userMap2).addOnSuccessListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Added to realtime database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                    auth.signOut()
                    startActivity(Intent(this, WelcomeScreenActivity::class.java))
                    finish()
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this, it.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fill all the details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

But only the toast "Buyer Account Created" is coming. "Added to realtime database" toast is not showing and it is also not going to the intent after that. and there is no error message in the logcat.
What can be the problem?

Comment: You're mixing two products here. `DatabaseReference` is a class from the API for the Realtime Database, while `db.collection("user").document(userId)` is an API for Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate - and the API from one can't be used to access the other.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I am trying to make a child in realtime database named user and it should contain other userid which we can bring from firebase uid. whenever someone creates and account, the user will be created both in firestore and database but doing this code it is completely skipping the database reference part.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just want that when the user is added to the db, it should also got added to the database. is there any better way to do it?

Comment: @AjaySatpati To understand better, do you need to write user details in Firestore as well as in the Realtime Database?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes I need to store the details in both

Comment: I understand. Now, is any of those Toast messages displayed?

Comment: @AlexMamo only this is displaying - "Buyer Account Created" and nothing else is displaying.

Comment: Is any of the `onFailure` even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo no, none of the onFailure are triggered